# Query works fine in phpmyadmin returns 0 rows when ran from php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm really stumped by this.  Here is the php:

**Update:**  I have escaped the inputs (before I did this a different way, but didn't know about mysql_real_escape_string).  Also, I replace the double quotes with single quotes, yet the same problem is happening.  Below is the updated code:

```
$request = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$colName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['col_name']);

function executeAssoc1($q)
{
    $r = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error() . ' ' . $q);
    $rass = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
    return $rass;
}

foreach(array_keys($_POST) as $pitem)
{

    if($pitem == (...what I want it to...))
    {
        $pitem_name = mysql_real_escape_string(rawurldecode($pitem));

        $qf = "SELECT * FROM possible_values WHERE table_id=$request AND col_name='$colName' AND value = '$pitem_name'";
        $qfr = executeAssoc1($qf);
        var_dump($pitem_name);
        echo '<br>';
        var_dump($qf);
        echo '<br>';
        var_dump($qfr);
    }

}
```

Here is part of what that code outputs during one loop:

> string(37) "1 .New England (Northeast region)"
>   string(122) "SELECT * FROM possible_values WHERE table_id=3 AND col_name='DIVISION' AND value = '1 .New England (Northeast region)'"
>   bool(false)

Now when I copy that query into the phpmyadmin SQL editor it does actually return a result.  I even tried using LIKE "%...%" as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931829/mysql-query-works-manually-but-returns-no-results-when-running-from-code) but the same thing happens (phpmyadmin returns a row, php returns 0 rows).

Comment: Escape your strings! That is calling for SQL Injections!

Comment: fixed the injection problem (I hope)

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are using the same database connection, database and table?

Comment: Have you tried with a semicolon? In mysqli that's a nono, but I can't remember how it worked in the old ext...

Comment: @Pekka  Yes I'm sure I'm using the right connection, database and table.  There are actually some queries that are successful such as this one:      
    SELECT * FROM possible_values WHERE table_id=3 AND col_name='DIVISION' AND value = '0'

Comment: See my new answer, I'm pretty sure that's it.

Comment: .... half-sure, that is. Your dump looks okay, and shows no sign of pluses. We'll see.

Comment: Are your field names really what you've posted, or do they differ? The reason I ask, if you've posted using "example names", but are using something different, make sure the field names aren't reserved words. phpMyAdmin is notorious for allowing you to use reserved words, but when you create an SQL statement outside (as in a PHP script), you find out quickly it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual on [**rawurldecode()**](https://www.php.net/rawurldecode):

> Note: rawurldecode() does not decode plus symbols ('+') into spaces. urldecode() does.

if you output your mySQL query, I bet your strting will look something like this:

```
1+.New+England+(Northeast+region)
```

try urldecode() as the manual entry suggests.

Comment: Ah, this led me to the ultimate cause.  For some reason my posts were replacing the period with underscores, so I told php to urlencode the string and furthermore do a str_replace('.','&#46;',$str) to fix the period.  Problem is I didn't decode the period again so the actual html was showing up as "... AND value = '1 &#46;New England (Northeast reg ...".  Grrr, now it works.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you should use single quotes instead of double quotes, ie:

```
SELECT * FROM possible_values WHERE table_id=3 AND col_name='DIVISION' AND value = '1 .New England (Northeast region)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes are not allowed for strings in SQL, as they are used for identifiers (like MySQL uses the backtick '`'). I think MySQL allows them for strings with some settings, but you shouldn't use them.

Technically that should return an error, so I don't think that's your problem.

What could be your problem is that you're using the old mysql extension, which may not support your mysql version.

Comment: I don't think that is it.  I'm running MySQL client version: 5.0.51b with PHP Version 5.2.6 and phpMyAdmin - 2.11.7

Comment: I remember so many times when people have had problems using the old mysql extension... so why use it? Use mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a typo, but

```
table_id=$request
```

should have quotes around it:

```
table_id='$request'
```